# Access request path within endpoint routing MapFallbackToFile()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating an .NET Core 3.0 app that launches an SPA. The routing in `Startup.cs` maps fallback routes to a file, `index.html`. Before serving the `index.html` file, I want to perform some custom validation, during which I need access to the original request route. The routing is defined as follows:

```cs
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                ......
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = x =>
                    {
                       // access original request path here?
                    }
                });
            });
```

How can I access the original request path within the `OnPrepareResponse` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I access the original request path within the OnPrepareResponse method?

Not sure why you need to do this. However, the [StaticFileResponseContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles.staticfileresponsecontext?view=aspnetcore-3.0) has a `Context` property that references the current [`HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.0) by which you can get original path:

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = x =>
    {
        var httpContext = x.Context;
        var path = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["path"];
       // now you get the original request path
    }
});
```